# EF 6.2.0 migrate.exe ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm setting up migrate.exe to run DB migration during VSTS release:
`migrate.exe DataAccess.dll /connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" /connectionString="Data Source=SQLXXX\DEV01;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Integrated Security=true;" /verbose`

Output:

```
VERBOSE: Target database is: 'XXXXX' (DataSource: SQLXXX\DEV01, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Explicit).
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Run()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)
ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

We have no code in Seed method. `No pending explicit migrations` is expected but we need the script to finish without an error for the release process to continue. How to fix this error?

[I raised this issue on EF6 GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/504)

Comment: You might try [supplying parameters to migrate.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx). Also, is there Seed() code?

Comment: No, there's nothing in Seed()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work I had to provide /startupConfigurationFile instead of /connectionString.